# PHP form that shows extra content based on user's response

Tags: php, forms, conditional-statements, hidden

I'm looking for a way to have a simple form (yes and no radio button questions) where if the user answers yes to all of the questions and hits submit, a hidden link to a file is made visible.  I'm no good at creating my own PHP yet...any suggestions?

```
<form name="myform" action="http://www.mydomain.com/myformhandler.php" method="POST">
<div align="center"><br>
<p>Question nubmer 1...</p><input type="radio" name="group1" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="No" checked> No<br>
<hr>
<p>Question nubmer 2...</p><input type="radio" name="group2" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="No"> No<br>
</div>
</form>
```

This would be visible if the answer to both questions is yes...

```
<div>
<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/somefile.pdf">grab the file here</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['group1']) && isset($_POST['group2'])) {
    if ($_POST['group1']=='Yes' && $_POST['group2']=='Water') print '<div><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/somefile.pdf">grab the file here</a></div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: It's for a client.  They want to make sure that the user says "yes" to certain criteria before they can download a pdf.

Comment: Thanks @ThA-B.  And oops, Water and Beer were supposed to read Yes and No, respectively.

Comment: @Jared Farrish - usability, readability, logic. first you check if you got what you were looking for and only then do consistency check.

Answer (score 0):

You basically just need to validate the values of the form that is being submitted.

```
$group1 = $_POST['group1'];
$group2 = $_POST['group2'];
if ($group1 == 'Yes' AND $group2 == 'Yes') echo 'My hidden data'[
```

Comment: POST is array so [] instead of () and must check if is set at all

Answer (score 0):

You're interested in the [GET/POST global arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php), in this case POST:

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="POST">
<div align="center"><br>
<p>Question nubmer 1...</p>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="No" checked> No<br>
<hr>
<p>Question nubmer 2...</p>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Water"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Beer"> No<br>
<input type="submit"/>
</div>
</form>
<?php 

if ($_POST['group1'] == 'Yes' && $_POST['group2'] == 'Water') {
    echo '<div><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/somefile.pdf">grab the file here</a></div>';
}

?>
```

Try it: http://jfcoder.com/test/grabfile.php

Answer (score 0):

$group1 =  $_POST('group1);
$group2 = $_POST('group2);

Then just use '==' (Equal or Set as) to check if they are the same:

if($group1 == 'Yes' && $group2 == 'Yes') print [grab the file here](http://www.mydomain.com/somefile.pdf)';

The code above will print the file. The reason is that the values of the operands are equal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm way late to this party but I thought the OP would like to know you could also do this in JavaScript without posting back to the page:

```
$('form[name="myform"]').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if($('input[name="group1"]').val() == "Yes" && $('input[name="group2"]').val() == "Water"){
        $('#linkToPDF').show();
    }    
});
```

You can see it working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ajp4r/